# How to fix 'Undefined columns selected' error in R?

Tags: r, subset

I'm working on a movie recomendation system (school project). For this project people have rated movies. When someone didn't see the movie NAs are shown in the dataset.   Therefore I'm looking for a way to get rid of the movies no one has seen. These are the lines where everyone has an NA.

The problem is that not all columns are used for rating the movies. Like the column with title. How can I subset the columns that contain a rating (4:17), and delete the rows in these columns that all contain NAs?

```
ratingMovie <- ratingMovie[, rowSums(is.na(ratingMovie)) != ncol(ratingMovie), ]
```

The code above I tried to run, but I'm not sure how I can add the subset within this code. When I run this code I get the error message 'undefined columns selected'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply with an `all(is.na)` function to get the index of the all NA rows. Then remove them from the dataframe. I've created an example here:

```
movieID <- c(1:5)
movieTitle <- c("Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie4", "Movie5")
student1 <- c(1, NA, 2:4)
student2 <- c(2, NA, 2, NA, 4)
student3 <- c(NA, NA, 1:3)

ratingMovie <- data.frame(movieID, movieTitle, student1, student2, student3)

  movieID movieTitle student1 student2 student3
1       1     Movie1        1        2       NA
2       2     Movie2       NA       NA       NA
3       3     Movie3        2        2        1
4       4     Movie4        3       NA        2
5       5     Movie5        4        4        3
>

index <- apply(ratingMovie[, c(3:5)], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
ratingMovie <- ratingMovie[!index,]

  movieID movieTitle student1 student2 student3
1       1     Movie1        1        2       NA
3       3     Movie3        2        2        1
4       4     Movie4        3       NA        2
5       5     Movie5        4        4        3
>
```

Comment: You could also do `ratingMovie[rowSums(is.na(ratingMovie[3:5])) != 3, ]`.